# how i fetch google review on website that also display on my website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

below this code to display a website code but not display .

```
<div id="google-reviews"></div>
```

this is the div where i dispay a google review.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
   $("#google-reviews").googlePlaces({
        placeId: 'myplaceid' //Find placeID @: https://developers.google.com/places/place-id
      , render: ['reviews']
      , min_rating: 4
      , max_rows:4
   });
});
</script>
```

this is the script for dispay review.

Answer (score 0):

If the code you've provided is all you have in place for this feature, it may be outdated and missing key dependencies.

In order for your javascript to properly execute, you'll need to register for a free API key and then insert the key in your javascript call.

- If using the Google Maps Library API JS, be sure to load it before executing your jQuery function. `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places"></script>` See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places for more details.
- If using the direct url method such as `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?placeid=ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4&key=YOUR_API_KEY`
  , see the Place Details Request section of https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/details

You'll then need to setup your javascript AJAX handler to parse the json results and populate your google-reviews div.